# Partial rendered via ajax does not contain javascript when it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

I have a partial that is being rendered via ajax and the result used to replace a div's contents. This partial is rendering correctly but when I inspect the element the javascript tag and it's javascript is not rendered in the browser. The partial is similar to the following

```
<style>
  /* some styles */
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("did it work");
</script>

<% @array.each do |el| %>
  <!--make table w/ array -->
<% end %>
```

When i inspect the element everything is there but the javascript. and i have evalJS: true on my Ajax.Updater options (i'm using prototype but i  don't think that makes any difference). The odd thing is that when i put the following in the action i can see the rendered template in the console w/ the js

```
test = render :partial => "my_partial.html.erb"
puts test
test
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look here: http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/ you will notice that the correct option name is evalScripts (but read about its use, because it has some limitations).

Comment: is there any way to get around the non global nature of evalScripts or will i need to localize my js inside that partial?

Comment: If you really want to define something in the global scope, you can simply use: `window.func = function() {}; window.prop = 3;` Also, everything already defined in the global scope will be available to you, so if you have a namespace defined you can use it normally like `MY_NS.my_method = function() {};`

Comment: nevermind, i got around it by defining the varable i needed in the initial page, and setting that var inside the ajax response

Comment: what was the solution here @grizzgreen